# How to create an index in MongoDB which calls a JS function via system.js?

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections viz. whitelist (id, count, expiry) and blacklist (id).
Now i would like to create an index such that when count>=200 then call a JS function which will remove the document from whitelist and add the id to blacklist.

So can i do this in Mongo using `db.collection.createindex({"count":1}, ???);`
or do i need to write a daemon to scan the entire collection? or is there any better method for the same?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking for what in a SQL relational database we would call a ["trigger"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger), which is something completely different from an "index" even in that world.

In the NoSQL world typically and especially with MongoDB, that sort of "server logic" is relegated to the "client" code operations rather than the server. Think of it as another part of the "scalability" philosphy of these products, where certain functions like "triggers" are taken away due to the stance that these "cost" a lot with distributed data.

So in order to do what you want you do it in "code" instead of defining a database "trigger". The process is simple enough, via [**`.findAndModify()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/) and other wrapping variants available to langauge API's:

```js
// Increment below 200 and return the modified document
var doc = db.whitelist.findAndModify({
    "query": { "_id": myId, "count": { "$lt": 200 } }
    "update": { "count": { "$inc": 1 } },
    "new": true
});

// Then remove the blacklist where the value meets conditions
if ( doc.hasOwnProperty("count") {
    if ( doc.count >= 200 ) 
        db.blacklist.remove({ "_id": myId });
}
```

Be careful with the actual language API method variant as the structure typically differs fromt the "query/update" keys as is provided in the shell method.

The basic principles remain the same. Modifiy and fetch, then remove from the other collection if your conditions are met. But it is "two" trips to the server, and there is no way to make the server "trigger" when such a condition is met by itself.

Answer (score 0):

```js
  db.whitelist.insert(doc);
  if(db.whitelist.find(criterion).count() >= 200) {
    var bulkRemove = db.whitelist.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
    var bulkInsert = db.blacklist.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();

    db.whitelist.find(criterion).forEach(
      function(doc){
        bulkInsert.insert({_id:doc._id});
        bulkRemove.find({doc._id}).removeOne();
      }
    );
    bulkInsert.execute();
    bulkRemove.execute();
  }
```

First, you insert the document as usual. Since `criterion` is going to use an index, the if clause should be determined fast and efficiently.

In case we have 200 or more documents matching that criterion, we use bulk operations to insert the ids into the blacklist and remove the documents from the whitelist, which will be executed in parallel.

The problem with only writing the `_id` to the backlist is that you need to check wether the criterion for being blacklisted is matched, so the `_id` needs to contain that criterion.

A better solution IMHO is to flag entries of a single collection using a field named `blacklisted` for individual entries or to use the aggregation framework to find blacklisted documents and write them to an a collection using the `out` pipeline stage. Sadly, you didn't give example data or a proper description of your use case, so you get an unspecified answer.